# Same output for diferent value on switch statement in python

Tags: python, switch-statement

So i have this code in phyton and i wanted to make so if the input is -1 the return will also be the string "zero"

```
def IntToStr(argument): 
    switcher = {0: "zero", 
                1: "one", 
                2: "two"} 

   return switcher.get(argument, "nothing")
```

so i wanted to know if there is any way that i can do something like:

```
switcher = { 
        0 or -1: "zero", 
        1: "one", 
        2: "two", 
    }
```

Comment: I did try the second dictionary and calling switcher[-1] works perfectly returning "zero". However, I have no idea why switcher[0] has a key error instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use a defaultdict (from collections) and express the keys as tuples that you expand in the final switcher content.  This way you don't have to repeat the values for common keys. You also don't need to repeat the default value everywhere you do a .get():

```
switcher = {(0,-1): "zero", 
            (1,)  : "one", 
            (2,)  : "two"}

from collections import defaultdict
switcher = defaultdict(lambda:"nothing",
           { k:v for ks,v in switcher.items() for k in ks })

switcher[-1] # 'zero'
switcher[0]  # 'zero'
switcher[1]  # 'one'
switcher[5]  # 'nothing'
```

You could generalize this by creating a function that will do the tuple expansion for any of your switching dictionaries:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def switch(d,default=None):
    return defaultdict(lambda:default,
           { k:v for ks,v in d.items() for k in ks })

switcher = switch({ (0,-1): "zero", 
                      (1,): "one", 
                      (2,): "two"},
                 default  = "nothing")
```

If what you're looking for is to simulate the behaviour of a switch/case statement, you can create a function that you use in a one-pass for-loop:

```
def switch(value): yield lambda *match: value in match
```

usage:

```
x = -1
for case in switch(x):
    if   case(-1,0) : r = "zero"
    elif case(1)    : r = "one"
    elif case(2)    : r = "two"
    else            : r = "nothing"
print(r) # zero
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add an additional key:

```
def IntToStr(argument): 
    switcher = {0: "zero", 
               -1: "zero",
                1: "one", 
                2: "two"} 

   return switcher.get(argument, "nothing")
```

Or you could add an extra line in the beginning of the function:

```
def IntToStr(argument): 
    argument = 0 if argument == -1 else argument
    switcher = {0: "zero", 
                1: "one", 
                2: "two"} 

   return switcher.get(argument, "nothing")
```